# How do you process multiple files shared from the iOS Files App

Tags: ios, files-app

I have an app that can open files shared with it.  If I select multiple files in the iOS Files app and share them with my app, my UIApplicationDelegate's `open url` handler is called once with the URL of the first file.  The remaining files are not reported to my delegate.  Does anyone know how to get the obtain the URLs of all the shared files?

I need a solution for iOS 11 and above.

Comment: I was looking everywhere for an answer to this.  There is a way, answered here (in case it of use to anyone who finds this):  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47203396/import-multiple-files-in-app-via-ios11-files-app